# connecting character array(string) in c

Tags: c, string

In my program user enters the line like this (5*(22+1)). Now I need to separate numbers and other characters. So I wrote the code like this.Is it possible to do this in c? or is there any easy way to this problem?I try this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char s[50];
    printf("Enter the line");
    gets(s);

    while(s[i]!='\n')
    {
        if(s[i]=='+' || s[i]=='-',s[i]=='*',s[i]=='/')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            char n[5];
            n=n+s[i];
        }
        printf("%s",n);

        i++;

       }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what's your problem, after all?

Comment: 1. Don't use `gets`. **Never** 2. `char n[5]; n = n + s[i];` I don't even know what that's supposed to mean. 3. `printf("%s",n);` `n` is not in this scope.

Comment: If by `n=n+s[i];` you meant to do string concatenation like you would in other languages, that does not work : if that's the case, check out the `strcat` function instead.

Comment: I got error "Array type char[5] is not assignable.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/?kw=sscanf) function. It might help at extracting decimals.

Also, your code has more mistakes:

```
if(s[i]=='+' || s[i]=='-',s[i]=='*',s[i]=='/')
```

Should be

```
if(s[i]=='+' || s[i]=='-' || s[i]=='*' || s[i]=='/')


char n[5];
n=n+s[i];
```

This is wrong. n is a pointer (a memory adress). There is no point in adding a character to it. If you wanted to make a concatenation, take a look at [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/?kw=strcat) function. Also note that you did not initialized n. In C, this is requred.

```
printf("%s",n);
```

Here n is out of scope. It exists just between braces:

```
{
char n[5]; 
n=n+s[i];
} //here n does not exists any more
```

To prevent this, declare n outside braces.